# Export all ways with keys piste:type: and aerialway

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is it possible to export all ways of piste:type and aerialway? Or maybe query these for a ski resort?
I would like to show these on a map in an iOS app. It would be nice to be able to export these sets either for each resort or whole country.

If this is not possible, can one query a resort or a country, in some way?

I have read some of the documentation, including on the API, but still is quite unsure how to correctly query the API or export these sets.

What I essentially need, is described with this query I have setup:
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/wvo

Thanks

Comment: Your question already contains the solution. Overpass API already allows to export specific objects in the given area or the whole world. What exactly is missing?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't completely aware that I could export it like this. Right now I am specifying a boundary box for my query, but I would like to query either the whole world, a country or a specific city. Since I am quite precise with what I am asking for and that it is ways that are not so common, I anticipate that the size of the response/exported file will be quite small for this to work alright.

Comment: Just try it. Alternatively you can download the [planet or a country/area extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) and filter it yourself, e.g. using osmium tool. This will however take more time than just using Overpass API.